# Can I call api microservice from another server and test it in my local from my code?

Tags: java, objectmapper

I am working on Production application where i have to call microservice to getListOfData in my application. So there is any way to test my method which i wrote for taking data from get api call from another application without creating mock data. I want to call real Api for testing my code ?

Comment: Call it like you call it now? It's not clear what the actual issue is.

Comment: (Noting that depending on context this can lead to weaker testing since you're not in control of what the API returns.)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DaveNewton. issue is - I am working on application which in java and i got some other apllication which is in .net so from .net side i got the api link and i have to call all these data from .net side to my java side. so for that i implement all the Interface and method to get data. so in current scenerio i want to test api call from my code.

Comment: Okay, but what's the *issue*? What problem are you having?